# Why the high voted answer is missing in hottest answers list?

Tags: discussion, support, score, hot-answers

In the [weekly hottest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/hot?filter=week) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) answers list I am unable to find the answer of [@Dennis Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910334/1249581) which was given on Jun 4 at 5:22 and at the moment has **99 upvotes**. However the answer by [@Baadshah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910313/1249581) given on Jun 4 at 5:21 having **41 upvotes** is listed as the hottest weekly answer.

Where is the Dennis's answer? Is it lost somewhere in cache?

Comment: It now has 100 upvotes :)

Comment: I find it strange that sometimes questions which have been asked before multiple times, get so much attention (and so many votes).

Comment: @Felix Yeah, that is true. I also can't understand why this question is sooo popular. I looks like exactly at 5 o'clock in the morning by UTC all the people rushed to upvote exactly this question, besides it was already answered many times, and almost every JS developer knows about `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is too short. From the bottom of the hottest answers page:

> Only top voted, non community-wiki answers of a *minimum length* are eligible

Emphasis mine.

Cheung's answer uses fewer that 50 characters, vs. Baadshah's answer which uses more than 250 characters. Somewhere between those two figures lies the threshold.

Comment: or maybe because [Baadshah's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16910313/1190388) reply has a lot of jQuery?

Comment: @hjpotter92: yeah, that must be it..

Comment: Hm... but how come the *hottesty* of the answer can be measured by its length? That's weird.

Comment: Presumably to encourage answers with a bit more substance to them. You often see one-liners be voted up rapidly because they are easier to read...

Comment: @VisioN min-length requirement is to offset [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/), when any idiot posting funny picture has their chance to get a fat portion of populist upvotes